# How can I loop a switch statement to check re-check a char? (C++)

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I want to make sure that the user enters either 'A','B','C' or 'D' in the default, but if they don't, have them re-enter a character until it matches one of the 4 characters listed above. How can I loop a switch statement to ensure that they've made a proper choice?

```
cout << "Enter the seat that you'd like to place the passenger in: "; cin >> aisle;
    aisle = toupper(aisle);
    switch (aisle){
        case 'A':
        temp = 0;
        break;
        case 'B':
        temp = 1;
        break;
        case 'C':
        temp = 2;
        break;
        case 'D':
        temp = 3;
        break;
        default:
            cout << "Input error, please re-enter an aisle: "; cin >> aisle;
            aisle = toupper(aisle);
        break;
    }
```

Temp is my method of converting the character to an index value to refer to an array.

Comment: simply add a loop around the switch and 'double break'.

Answer (score 1):

I would set a flag in the `default` case and put the whole thing into a `do-while` loop, like this:

```
bool tryAgain = false;
do
{
    cout << "Enter the seat that you'd like to place the passenger in: "; cin >> aisle;
    aisle = toupper(aisle);
    switch (aisle){
        case 'A':
            temp = 0;
            break;
        case 'B':
            temp = 1;
            break;
        case 'C':
            temp = 2;
            break;
        case 'D':
            temp = 3;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Input error, please re-enter an aisle (A, B, C, or D)";
            tryAgain = true;
            break;
    }
}
while (tryAgain);
```

Comment: don't forget to set `tryAgain` to false at the beginning of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without the switch statement. For example

```
#include <cstring>

//...

int temp = -1;

cout << "Enter the seat that you'd like to place the passenger in: "; 

do
{
    cin >> aisle;
    aisle = toupper(aisle);

    const char *seats = "ABCD";

    const char *p = strchr( seats, aisle );

    temp = ( p == NULL ? -1 : p - seats ); 

    if ( temp == -1 )
    {
        cout << "Input error, please re-enter an aisle: ";
    }
} while ( temp == -1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `while` loop around the `switch` statement.

```
while ( true )
{
   bool breakLoop = true;
   cout << "Enter the seat that you'd like to place the passenger in: ";
   cin >> aisle;
   aisle = toupper(aisle);
   switch (aisle){
      case 'A':
         temp = 0;
         break;
      case 'B':
         temp = 1;
         break;
      case 'C':
         temp = 2;
         break;
      case 'D':
         temp = 3;
         break;
      default:
         cout << "Input error.";
         breakLoop = false;
   }

   if ( breakLoop )
   {
      break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `goto` statement if you want, something like this :

```
retry:
cout << "Enter the seat that you'd like to place the passenger in: "; 
cin >> aisle;
aisle = toupper(aisle);

switch (aisle){
    case 'A':
        temp = 0;
        break;
    case 'B':
        temp = 1;
        break;
    case 'C':
        temp = 2;
        break;
    case 'D':
        temp = 3;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Invalid input, please try again. " << endl;
        goto retry;
    break;
}
```

I would not recommend to use `goto` if your script is a bit lengthy.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged this as C++ and used std::cin.  Perhaps you should consider std::strings.

In C++:

```
 int retVal = -1;

 // for simplicity during development, I use ss for input
 std::stringstream ss;
 ss << "53d";             // change test sequence here

 std::cout << "Enter seat you'd like to place the passenger in: ";

 char aisle;
 do
 {
    ss >> aisle; // use ss instead of cin for development

    // for development, echo user inputs, 
    // but remove the following before release
    std::cout << "  " << aisle << std::endl;

    // toupper returns an int, but aisle is char
    aisle = static_cast<char>(toupper(aisle));

    const std::string Seats = "ABCD";

    size_t indx = Seats.find(aisle);

    if(indx != std::string::npos) // found aisle in Seats
    {
       retVal = aisle - 'A'; // return 0, 1, 2, or 3
       break;  // found - aisle is in range
    }

    std::cout << "Input error, please re-enter an aisle: ";

 } while(true);

 std::cout << "aisle: " << aisle << "   retVal: " << retVal << std::endl;
```